# MySQL Select Combined Unique

Tags: mysql, select, join

```
Table: Contacts
id    | name  | has_this
------------------------
1     | Jeff  | 0
2     | Terry | 1
3     | Tom   | 0
4     | Henry | 1

Table: has_thing
id    | owner | thing
---------------------
1     | Terry | stuff
2     | Tom   | stuff
3     | Toby  | stuff
```

I want a SELECT that will return

```
name  | thing
-------------
Terry | stuff
Tom   | stuff
Henry | 
Toby  | stuff
```

Basically, I think I want a JOIN but I want any name that is in table 2(has_thing) that is not in table 1 to be included the output and any name that is in table 1(Contacts) WHERE has_this=1 to be included in the output

Comment: Where is your code? Have u try it? It using `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: @ColourDalnet MySQL doesn't have `FULL OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: @Barmar : I'm sorry, yes you are right. I edit it, your previous comment should do that.

Comment: You need `OUTER JOIN` and `UNION`. Please show us the code have u tried and if still have problem, edit your question and we are gladly to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT name, MAX(thing) as thing
FROM (SELECT c.name, h.thing
      FROM Contacts AS c
      JOIN has_thing AS h ON c.name = h.name
      UNION
      SELECT name, ''
      FROM Contacts
      WHERE has_thing = 1) AS subquery
GROUP BY name
```

`MAX(thing)` ensures that we pick up the non-empty `thing` from the first query when the contact has `has_thing = 1`.

You could also do it with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT c.name, IFNULL(h.thing, '') AS thing
FROM Contacts AS c
LEFT JOIN has_thing AS h ON c.name = h.name
WHERE c.has_thing = 1
OR h.name IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been trying with LEFT JOIN. I totally forgot about UNION! It's not something I've used much, but I think it's going to be what I need...

Comment: I got it working perfectly (or so it seems?) using a subquery, UNION, and LEFT JOIN. (Applying what you taught me to a more specific situation.) Thank you very much!